# How to split one string into multiple variables in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I've been looking for a solution and found similar questions, only they were attempting to split sentences with spaces between them, and the answers do not work for my situation.

Currently a variable is being set to something a string like this:
`ABCDE-123456`
and I would like to split that into 2 variables, while eliminating the "**-**". i.e.:
`var1=ABCDE`
`var2=123456`

How is it possible to accomplish this?

---

This is the solution that worked for me:
`var1=$(echo $STR | cut -f1 -d-)`
`var2=$(echo $STR | cut -f2 -d-)`

Is it possible to use the **cut** command that will work without a delimiter (each character gets set as a variable)?

`var1=$(echo $STR | cut -f1 -d?)`
`var2=$(echo $STR | cut -f1 -d?)`
`var3=$(echo $STR | cut -f1 -d?)`
`etc.`

Comment: For your second question, see @mkb's comment to my answer below - that's definitely the way to go!

Comment: See my edited answer for one way to read individual characters into an array.

Comment: Here is the same thing in a more concise form:
var1=$(cut -f1 -d- <<<$STR)

Answer (score 198, accepted):

*If* your solution doesn't have to be general, i.e. only needs to work for strings like your example, you could do:

```
var1=$(echo $STR | cut -f1 -d-)
var2=$(echo $STR | cut -f2 -d-)
```

I chose `cut` here because you could simply extend the code for a few more variables...

Comment: Can you look at my post again and see if you have a solution for the followup question? thanks!

Comment: You can use `cut` to cut characters too! `cut -c1` for example.

Comment: Although this is very simple to read and write, is a very slow solution because forces you to read twice the same data ($STR) ... if you care of your script performace, the @anubhava solution is much better

Comment: Apart from being an ugly last-resort solution, this has a bug: You should absolutely use double quotes in `echo "$STR"` unless you specifically want the shell to expand any wildcards in the string as a side effect.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: You're right about double quotes of course, though I did point out this solution wasn't general.  However I think your assessment is a bit unfair - for some people this solution may be more readable (and hence extensible etc) than some others, and doesn't completely rely on arcane bash feature that wouldn't translate to other shells.  I suspect that's why my solution, though less elegant, continues to get votes periodically...

Answer (score 316):

To split a string separated by `-`, you can use `read` with `IFS`:

```
$ IFS=- read -r var1 var2 <<< ABCDE-123456
$ echo "$var1"
ABCDE
$ echo "$var2"
123456
```

**Edit:**

Here is how you can read each individual character into array elements:

```
$ read -ra foo <<<"$(echo "ABCDE-123456" | sed 's/./& /g')"
```

Dump the array:

```
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo='([0]="A" [1]="B" [2]="C" [3]="D" [4]="E" [5]="-" [6]="1" [7]="2" [8]="3" [9]="4" [10]="5" [11]="6")'
```

If there are spaces in the string:

```
$ IFS=$'\v' read -ra foo <<<"$(echo "ABCDE 123456" | sed $'s/./&\v/g')"
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo='([0]="A" [1]="B" [2]="C" [3]="D" [4]="E" [5]=" " [6]="1" [7]="2" [8]="3" [9]="4" [10]="5" [11]="6")'
```

Comment: this solution also has the benefit that if delimiter is not present, the `var2` will be empty

Comment: The `read` does not work inside loops with input redirects. `read` will pick a wrong file descriptor to read from.

Comment: I initially gave this answer a plus as an elegant solution, but now figured out it works differently on Bash v3 and v4, thereby doesn't work on macos with pre-installed bash v3. Unfortunatelly I can't downvote the answer now since the vote is locked :(

Comment: A more general, correct, way: `IFS=- read -r -d '' var1 var2 < <(printf %s "ABCDE-123456")`. The `-r -d ''` and `<(printf %s ...)` are important

Comment: @akwky: Use an alternate [file descriptor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089). `while read -r line <&3; do ssh_or_something "$line"; done 3<file`

Comment: @JerryGreen: How does it not work with Bash 3 in MacOS? I'm not seeing a difference.

Answer (score 280):

If you know it's going to be just two fields, you can skip the extra subprocesses like this, using :

```
var1=${STR%-*}
var2=${STR#*-}
```

What does this do? `${STR%-*}` deletes the shortest substring of `$STR` that matches the pattern `-*` starting from the end of the string. `${STR#*-}` does the same, but with the `*-` pattern and starting from the beginning of the string. They each have counterparts `%%` and `##` which find the *longest* anchored pattern match. If anyone has a helpful mnemonic to remember which does which, let me know! I always have to try both to remember.

See the [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for more information.

Comment: Plus 1 For knowing your POSIX shell features, avoiding expensive forks and pipes, and the absence of bashisms.

Comment: Dunno about "absence of bashisms" considering that this is already moderately cryptic .... if your delimiter is a newline instead of a hyphen, then it becomes even more cryptic. On the other hand, *it works with newlines*, so there's that.

Comment: A description of how this actually works would be helpful

Comment: Well explained. Thanks. What is official name of this functionality? Is there any documentation for it?

Comment: I've finally found documentation for it: [Shell-Parameter-Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Mnemonic: "#" is to the left of "%" on a standard keyboard, so "#" removes a prefix (on the left), and "%" removes a suffix (on the right).

Comment: Simplest answer that worked with zero modifications. Thank you!

Comment: this didnt work for me in bash 5.0 or zsh 5.8

Comment: Another mnemonic, since your keyboard may be different (and some just "feel" the layout, rather than know it): the % symbol is typically encountered *after* a number, e.g. 90%, hence it is a suffix. The # symbol is typically leading comments or even just the first char in hashtags, so it's a common prefix. The purpose of both modifiers is to remove, one just removes a prefix (#), the other removes the suffix (%).

Answer (score 55):

Sounds like a job for `set` with a custom `IFS`.

```
IFS=-
set $STR
var1=$1
var2=$2
```

(You will want to do this in a function with a `local IFS` so you don't mess up other parts of your script where you require `IFS` to be what you expect.)

Comment: Nice - I knew about `$IFS` but hadn't seen how it could be used.

Comment: I used triplee's example and it worked exactly as advertised! Just change last two lines to
<pre>
myvar1=`echo $1` && myvar2=`echo $2`
</pre>
if you need to store them throughout a script with several "thrown" variables.

Comment: No, [don't use a useless `echo` in backticks](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#echo).

Comment: This is a really sweet solution if we need to write something that is not Bash specific. To handle `IFS` troubles, one can add `OLDIFS=$IFS` at the beginning before overwriting it, and then add `IFS=$OLDIFS` just after the `set` line.

Comment: @DanielAndersson That's a good and common workaround as well if you don't want to or cannot use a function with a `local IFS` (which isn't entirely portable anyway).

Comment: Maybe add a `set -f` to disable pathname expansion before `set -- $STR`, or it will capture paths files names if `$STR` contains patterns.

Comment: @DanielAndersson I got your point, but this will do the wrong thing if `IFS` is originally unset. I don't know whether that could happen in a normal bash environment, but I am meaning my comment in a more general sense. Setting a variable to a custom value and restoring it later is surprisingly complicated if it is not known in advance whether or not that variable originally is set.

Comment: @Binarus Good point -- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls #49 has some words about this. In practice I like to use subshells for things like this (the last suggestion in the link), temporary options, etc., but sometimes that is too limiting.

Comment: You can do something like `oldIFS=${IFS-__unset__}` but restoring from that is arguably clunky at best.

Answer (score 38):

Using bash regex capabilities:

```
re="^([^-]+)-(.*)$"
[[ "ABCDE-123456" =~ $re ]] && var1="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" && var2="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
echo $var1
echo $var2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ABCDE
123456
```

Comment: Love pre-defining the `re` for later use(s)!