# How to parse a string into variables?

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, arguments

I know how to parse a string into variables in the manner [of this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520623/how-to-split-one-string-into-multiple-variables-in-bash-shell), e.g.

```
ABCDE-123456
```

becomes:

```
var1=ABCDE
var2=123456
```

via, say, `cut`. I can do that in one script, no problem.

But I have a few dozen scripts which parse strings/arguments all in the same fashion (same arguments & variables, i.e. same parsing strategy).
And sometimes I need to make a change or **add a variable** to the parsing mechanism.

Of course, I could go through every one of my dozens of scripts and change the parsing manually (even if just copy & paste), but that would be tedious and more error-prone to bugs/mistakes.

**Is there a modular way to do parse strings/arguments as such?**

I thought of writing a script which parses the string/args into variables and then `export`s, but the `export` command does not work form child-to-parent, (only vice-versa).

Comment: Source the parsing script don't execute it.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work:

```
parse_it () {
    SEP=${SEP--}
    string=$1
    names=${@:2}

    IFS="$SEP" read $names <<< "$string"
}

$ parse_it ABCDE-123456 var1 var2
$ echo "$var1"
ABCDE
$ echo "$var2"
123456
$ SEP=: parse_it "foo:bar:baz" id1 id2 id3
$ echo $id2
bar
```

The first argument is the string to parse, the remaining arguments are names of variables that get passed to `read` as the variables to set. (Not quoting `$names` here is intentional, as we will let the shell split the string into multiple words, one per variable. Valid variable names consist of only _, letters, and numbers, so there are no worries about undesired word splitting or pathname generation by not quoting `$names`). The function assumes the string uses a single separator of "-", which can be overridden via the environment.

For more complex parsing, you may want to use a custom regular expression (`bash` 4 or later required for the `-g` flag to `declare`):

```
parse_it () {
    reg_ex=$1
    string=$2
    shift 2
    [[ $string =~ $reg_ex ]] || return
    i=1
    for name; do
        declare -g "$name=${BASH_REMATCH[i++]}"
    done
}

$ parse_it '(.*)-(.*):(.*)' "abc-123:xyz" id1 id2 id3
$ echo "$id2"
123
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is to write your function in one script and include it in all of your other scripts.
You can include other shell scripts by the `source` or `.` command.

For example, you can define your parse function in `parseString.sh`

```
function parseString {
    ...
}
```

And then in any of your other script, do

```
source parseString.sh
# now we can call parseString function
parseString abcde-12345
```