# How to not expand a command-substitution into multiple parameters

Tags: shell, fish

So according [to the docs](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/#expand-command-substitution) a command written over many lines will expand to multiple parameters. This disagrees with the bash behaviour. For example

hello.lua:

```
local msg = "Hello, world!" 
return msg
```

fish>

```
redis-cli EVAL (cat hello.lua) 0
```

Fails -

Whereas `redis-cli EVAL "$(cat hello.lua)" 0` will succeed in bash. My question is how to prevent the `(cat hello.lua)` substitution from splitting into multiple parameters due to line breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fish does not have a direct analog to bash's "$(...)". The current best technique in fish is to manipulate `$IFS`, which are the characters that trigger splitting. You can make it empty:

```
set -l IFS
redis-cli EVAL (cat hello.lua) 0
```

This will pass the entire contents of `hello.lua` as a single argument.

Assuming you don't want your IFS changes to stick around, you can scope the change to a function, or to a block:

```
begin
  set -l IFS
  redis-cli EVAL (cat hello.lua) 0
end
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Since Fish aims to be a more practical shell at the cost of some standard compliance, is there a chance we might ever see argument splitting/joining with a built-in function or symbol? [These things are very painful](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10520623/3467349)

Comment: Yes, there's an [old proposal](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/445) of mine, and a separate proposal for a `string` builtin that will support splitting and joining is being [actively worked on](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/156) too.