# scp: how to copy a file from remote server with a filter

Tags: linux, shell, scp

I am trying to use scp to copy large log files from a remote server. However I want only the lines in remote log file that has a string "Fail".
This is how I am doing it currently

```
scp user@ip:remote_folder/logfile* /localfolder
```

This copies all the files starting with logfile in remote server to my local folder. The files are pretty large and I need to copy only the lines in those log file, containing the string "Fail" from remote server. Can any body tell me how to do this? Can I use cat or grep command?

Comment: A little tip: if you are transferring text files, then using the `-C` flag to `ssh`/`scp` to enable compression can make things *much* faster over a slow connection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grep` on the remote machine and filter the output into file name and content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

BASEDIR=~/temp/log

IFS=$'\n'
for match in `ssh user@ip grep -r Fail "remote_folder/logfile*"`
do
    IFS=: read file line <<< $match
    mkdir -p `dirname $BASEDIR/$file`
    echo $line >> $BASEDIR/$file
done
```

You might want to look at an explanation to [`IFS` in combination with `read`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10527046/1525423).

Answer (score 2):

`ssh user@ip grep Fail remote_folder/logfile*`

Comment: You might want to quote the file name argument, because your shell will expand it locally if you have globbing enabled, and it matches a local list of files (or you have `nullglob` enabled in your shell).